# How to add onclick with mapping in typescript react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface, mapping, navbar

So i have this code

Dropdown.tsx

```
export interface IDropdownOptions {
  id: number
  title: string
  href: string
  typeIcon: IconType
  action?: (event: React.MouseEvent) => void
}

interface IDropdownProps {
  options: IDropdownOptions[]
  className?: string
}

const DropdownComponent: React.FC<IDropdownProps> = ({ className, options }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={classNames(
        'dropdown dropdown-bottom dropdown-end border-[1px] w-[180px] h-[36px] gap-[8px] items-center flex rounded-[8px] border-[#D5D5D5] px-[12px] py-[9px] cursor-pointer',
        className
      )}
    >
      <div tabIndex={0} className='flex gap-[4px] items-center'>
        <div className='w-[16px] h-[16px] flex items-center justify-center'>
          <Icon className='w-[12px] h-[12px]' type='User' />
        </div>
        <div className='text-[12px] font-normal leading-[18px] w-[116px]'>Username</div>
      </div>
      <div className='w-[16px] h-[16px] flex items-center justify-center'>
        <Icon className='w-[8px] h-[4px]' type='Dropdown' />
      </div>
      <ul
        tabIndex={0}
        className='dropdown-content menu p-2 shadow bg-base-100 w-[180px] rounded-[8px]'
      >
        {options.map((option) => (
          <li
            key={option.id}
            className='my-1 items-center flex cursor-pointer justify-center'
            onClick={option.action}
          >
            <a href={option.href}>
              <div className='flex gap-[4px] items-center w-full'>
                <div className='w-[16px] h-[16px] flex items-center justify-center'>
                  <Icon className='w-[12px] h-[12px]' type={option.typeIcon} />
                </div>
                <div className='text-[12px] font-normal leading-[18px] w-[116px]'>
                  {option.title}
                </div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Navbar.tsx

```
const optionsDropdown: IDropdownOptions[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Chat',
    href: '/',
    typeIcon: 'User',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Notifications',
    href: '/',
    typeIcon: 'User',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'Settings',
    href: '/',
    typeIcon: 'User',
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'Logout',
    href: '/',
    typeIcon: 'User',
  },
]

const Navbar = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const { auth } = useAuth()
  const [activePath, setActivePath] = useState<string>('/')
  const location = useLocation()

  useEffect(() => {
    setActivePath(location.pathname)
  }, [location.pathname])

  const handleLogout = () => {
    dispatch(logout())
    navigate('/login')
  }

  return (
    <>
      {auth && (
        <div className='border-b border-grey-outline'>
          <div className='navbar container mx-auto'>
            <div className='navbar-start'>
              <div className='dropdown'>
                <label tabIndex={0} className='btn btn-ghost lg:hidden'>
                  <svg
                    xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
                    className='h-5 w-5'
                    fill='none'
                    viewBox='0 0 24 24'
                    stroke='currentColor'
                  >
                    <path
                      strokeLinecap='round'
                      strokeLinejoin='round'
                      strokeWidth='2'
                      d='M4 6h16M4 12h8m-8 6h16'
                    />
                  </svg>
                </label>
                <ul
                  tabIndex={0}
                  className='menu menu-compact dropdown-content mt-3 p-2 shadow bg-base-100 rounded-box w-52'
                >
                  {navigationData.map((item) => (
                    <li key={item.name}>
                      <Link
                        to={item.href}
                        className={`text-white font-medium hover:bg-blue-surface active:bg-blue-surface active:text-blue ${
                          activePath === item.href ? 'bg-blue-surface text-blue' : ''
                        }`}
                      >
                        {item.name}
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                  ))}
                </ul>
              </div>
              <a className='normal-case text-[24px] text-blue mr-[34px]'>Industry.</a>
              <ul className='menu menu-horizontal px-1 hidden lg:flex gap-[32px]'>
                {navigationData.map((item) => (
                  <li key={item.name}>
                    <Link
                      to={item.href}
                      className={`text-white font-medium hover:bg-blue-surface active:bg-blue-surface active:text-blue ${
                        activePath === item.href ? 'bg-blue-surface text-blue' : ''
                      }`}
                    >
                      {item.name}
                    </Link>
                  </li>
                ))}
              </ul>
            </div>

            <div className='navbar-end'>
              <DropdownComponent options={optionsDropdown} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

The problem is I want to add a different functions when i clicked on different dropdown button but I don't know how to do it.

I already tried to add

```
actions: {handleLogout}
```

to the interface on the optionsDropdown but still it won't work. How do i implement handleLogout to the actions?

Comment: Replace option.actions by option.action (without s)

Comment: now i got this new error:

(property) handleLogout: any
Type '{ handleLogout: any; }' is not assignable to type '(event: MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>) => void'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'handleLogout' does not exist in type '(event: MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>) => void'.ts(2322)
DropdownComponent.tsx(11, 3): The expected type comes from property 'action' which is declared here on type 'IDropdownOptions'
No value exists in scope for the shorthand property 'handleLogout'. Either declare one or provide an initializer.ts(18004)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the functions directly in `optionsDropdown` declaration:

```
const Navbar = () => {
  ...
  const optionsDropdown: IDropdownOptions[] = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Chat',
      href: '/',
      typeIcon: 'User',
      action: () => {
        console.log('do something');
      },
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Notifications',
      href: '/',
      typeIcon: 'User',
      action: () => {
        console.log('do something');
      },
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: 'Settings',
      href: '/',
      typeIcon: 'User',
      action: () => {
        console.log('do something');
      },
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      title: 'Logout',
      href: '/',
      typeIcon: 'User',
      action: () => {
        dispatch(logout());
        navigate('/login');
      },
    },
  ];
};
```

Change `IDropdownOptions` interface to:

```
export interface IDropdownOptions {
  id: number
  title: string
  href: string
  typeIcon: IconType
  action: () => void
}
```

And call the `action` with:

```
<li
  key={option.id}
  className='my-1 items-center flex cursor-pointer justify-center'
  onClick={() => option.action()}
>
```

Comment: It worked man! Thank you so much for your help. Appreciate it!